# How do I control the address generated in address bar of browser after executing a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have written, for practice, a simple webpage that will display to the user a drop down menu. The user will select a number and hit the `Submit` button.

After that, the servlet will be executed and will send back a list of even numbers.

[image]

Looking at the address in the address bar of the web browser, it is:

`http://localhost:8080/FindEvenOdd/FindEvenOdd`

I want it to be **`http://localhost:8080/FindEvenOdd/Result`**

How do I do that ?
My DD looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Evens</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>FindIt</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Evens</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/FindEvenOdd</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> List of Even/Odd Numbers </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="FindEvenOdd">
        <center>
            <select name="number" size="1">
                <option> <50
                <option> <100
                <option> <150
            </select>
        </center>
            <center>
                <input type="SUBMIT">
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### What I tried

I changed the `action="FindEvenOdd"` to `action="Result"`

i changed the `<url-pattern>` to Result

I did the above two things simultaneously but got a 404.
So,
What do I do to get **`http://localhost:8080/FindEvenOdd/Result`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tried is almost correct. The `url-pattern` must be set to `/Result`.

Some notes though:

- always put your classes in a package. Not in the default package
- generate valid HTML5. `center` is a tag that shouldn't be used for a long time, and your select box is invalid HTML.
- Learn servlet 3.0 rather than servlet 2.4.

Comment: Yes, Sir, I will. I have next-to-none knowledge of HTML. Also, I will focus on Servlet 3.0 :)
Just a question: the value of `action` in HTML **must match exactly** the value of `url-pattern` in DD. correct ?

Comment: No. As its name indicates, url-pattern contains a pattern of URLs mapped to the servlet. It could be *.action or /foo/* for example. The pattern is always take relative to the webapp's context path (/FindEvenOdd in your case). The action attribute in the HTML form is an absolute or relative URL. If relative (i.e. if it doesn't start with `/`), then it's relative to the path you see in the address bar of the browser. If it's absolute (i.e. it starts with a `/`), then it will always start at the root of the web server.

Comment: So, in your case, using the relative URL `Result` is the same as using the absolute URL `/FindEvenOdd/Result`. ALways remember that the browser doesn't know anything about Java webapps. The context path of an application is something Java-webapp-related, and the browser doesn't know and care is the page was generated by a Java webapp, or by a static file, or by a pool of gremlins.

Comment: As for your second comment, I figured that out :) There is a name that the user knows, then there is a deployment name and an actual file name for the Servlet. **How much do Servlet 2.4 and Servlet 3.0 differ?** They only good book I got on servlets was Head First and its on 2.4

Comment: Servlet 3.0 allows using Java annotations to declare and map servlets and other components, rather than the web.xml file. It makes things easier. It also has support for file upload and asynchronous reaquest handling, IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

change url pattern to `/FindEvenOdd/Result` and try

Answer (score 0):

In order to change URL, you need a redirect in the servlet.

```
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(contextPath + "/Result") );
```